# How to get attribute info of wms layer published in geoserver in a popup via. Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have published a feature in geoserver which I am successfully accessing by leaflet with its basemap. Now I need to fetch the attribute information of feature onclick in a popup.

I used example (https://gist.github.com/rclark/6908938) as it is, but didn't succeed, on click it doesn't show anything, neither any error in console. I replaced "map" with "mapid" i.e mapid for me. I m not understanding whats happening kindly help me with this. Thanks.....

my html file is - test.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Leaflet</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="http://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="BetterWMS.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var map = new L.Map('map', {center: new L.LatLng(30.176166666666667,79.14880555555557), zoom: 8});
            var osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
            map.addLayer(osm);
            var Forest_Data = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms', {
        format: 'image/png',layers: 'cite:Forest_Data',transparent: 'true'
     }).addTo(map);

     </script>
    </body>
    </html>


and "BetterWMS.js" file is -

L.TileLayer.BetterWMS = L.TileLayer.WMS.extend({

  onAdd: function (mapid) {
    // Triggered when the layer is added to a map.
    //   Register a click listener, then do all the upstream WMS things
    L.TileLayer.WMS.prototype.onAdd.call(this, mapid);
    map.on('click', this.getFeatureInfo, this);
  },

  onRemove: function (mapid) {
    // Triggered when the layer is removed from a map.
    //   Unregister a click listener, then do all the upstream WMS things
    L.TileLayer.WMS.prototype.onRemove.call(this, mapid);
    map.off('click', this.getFeatureInfo, this);
  },

  getFeatureInfo: function (evt) {
    // Make an AJAX request to the server and hope for the best
    var url = this.getFeatureInfoUrl(evt.latlng),
        showResults = L.Util.bind(this.showGetFeatureInfo, this);
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        var err = typeof data === 'string' ? null : data;
        showResults(err, evt.latlng, data);
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        showResults(error);  
      }
    });
  },

  getFeatureInfoUrl: function (latlng) {
    // Construct a GetFeatureInfo request URL given a point
    var point = this._map.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng, this._map.getZoom()),
        size = this._map.getSize(),

        params = {
          request: 'GetFeatureInfo',
          service: 'WMS',
          srs: 'EPSG:4326',
          styles: this.wmsParams.styles,
          transparent: this.wmsParams.transparent,
          version: this.wmsParams.version,      
          format: this.wmsParams.format,
          bbox: this._map.getBounds().toBBoxString(),
          height: size.y,
          width: size.x,
          layers: this.wmsParams.layers,
          query_layers: this.wmsParams.layers,
          info_format: 'text/html'
        };

    params[params.version === '1.3.0' ? 'i' : 'x'] = point.x;
    params[params.version === '1.3.0' ? 'j' : 'y'] = point.y;

    return this._url + L.Util.getParamString(params, this._url, true);
  },

  showGetFeatureInfo: function (err, latlng, content) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); return; } // do nothing if there's an error

    // Otherwise show the content in a popup, or something.
    L.popup({ maxWidth: 800})
      .setLatLng(latlng)
      .setContent(content)
      .openOn(this._map);
  }
});

L.tileLayer.betterWms = function (url, options) {
  return new L.TileLayer.BetterWMS(url, options);  
};
```

I am expecting a simple popup on clicking WMS layer with attribute information of the feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

above code is right only one replacement was needed, instead of -
var Forest_Data = L.tileLayer.wms , it will be -
var Forest_Data = L.tileLayer.betterWMS

Answer (score 1):

You defined your `Forest_Data` as a default WMS object :

`var Forest_Data = L.tileLayer.wms (...)`

You need to use the new object you defined instead. See in your link's example :

`L.tileLayer.betterWms(...)`

Comment: thanks alot @Joffrey, now I am getting popup, but CORS error persist i.e No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I m using CORS extension for chrome and getting popup. But I want to rectify it by code. How to do that?

Comment: I have tried following things - uncommented CORS filters in web.xml in geoserver

Comment: added header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"  in my html file also tried it as php can anyone please suggest where to put this codes ??

Comment: This header must be set in the Geoserver's answers. Your edition of web.xml should have solved the problem : https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html#enable-cors

Did you restart the server after the modification? 

Otherwise, you should create a new question about this on GIS : https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, I tried restarting server, but same error exist.